# Automatic weights deforming my character rig

Tags: modeling, mesh, rigging, bones, vertex-weights

I'm making my second rig, and I'm having problems when I want to set the mesh as the armature parent. Once I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> to open the menu and select "With automatic weights" it deforms the mesh.

I have looked on several pages and done everything they said, setting Roll option to 0, or setting the pole angle to 0 to align all the bones.

What else can I do?

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: Can you give us a picture? Could help a lot :) before and after the automatic weights

Comment: Can you put a download link of your blender project? I realized the problem but not so sure. i want to check it

Comment: Sure, here is: https://www.dropbox.com/s/53synifdr10e088/Model1.blend?dl=0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have got multiple problem with your model.

1. Your Character's head has half an extra meshes with the mirror modifier.
   I select the extra vertices and deleted them.
2. You have overlapping faces on within the model.
   I removed the extra faces with <kbd>W</kbd> key, then select "remove double"
3. The body of your character have normals facing in the opposite direction.
   I corrected the the normals with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>N</kbd>.

Here is the blend file after I corrected those issues. The weights are now correctly applied.

[image]

**Extra note**
I must say I have noticed that your have rigged the hand IK object to the hand bone. Shouldn't it be on the lower arm bone, you might have to get a better tutorial on the subject. Your bone objects are not rotated to the correct front facing position at rest. Always check your bone orientation with it's local axis turned on.

Here is the improved rig.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. Can you give me indications on how do you manage to solve the issues?

Comment: I have build on my answer. You may want to read the Extra note.